# Android Webview multiply method can't be resolved

Tags: java, android, webview

Im currently writing an app that takes my website into it. I also made requests for permissions but now `onCreate`,`setContentView` and `findViewById` cant be resolved (they are almost at the end of the coding).
Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package org.youtivity.youtivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
                // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
            }
        }

        private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
            int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
            if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission callback called-------");
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                    Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                    // Initialize the map with both permissions
                    perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    // Fill with actual results from user
                    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                            perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                        // Check for both permissions
                        if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                                && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "sms & location services permission granted");
                            // process the normal flow
                            //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                            //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
                         // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                            //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                showDialogOK("SMS and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                switch (which) {
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                        checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                        break;
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                        // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                            //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                            //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                                //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }





        /**
         * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
         */
        public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
               // view.loadUrl(url);
               // return true;
                String url2="https://www.youtivity.org/";
                // all links  with in ur site will be open inside the webview
                //links that start ur domain example(http://www.example.com/)
                if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                    return false;
                }
                // all links that points outside the site will be open in a normal android browser
                else  {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            }
        }


        /**
         * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
         * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
         */
        public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
                // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        }


        WebView mWebView;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override //<------Error HERE (does not overwrite)
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //<------Error HERE (onCreate)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<------Error HERE (setContentView)
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);//<------Error HERE (findViewById)
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());//<------Error HERE (GeoWebViewClient)

            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noinet.html");

                }
            });
            mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtivity.org");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            }
            else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy and paste the whole file or do it in chunks? If this is the whole file then it looks to me like you have one too many closing brackets after `public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient`. So you've actually closed out the activity class. The following class `public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient` is seen as outside the activity rather than an embedded class and those last function appear to be just hanging out there not part of any class.

Those two consecutive lines with } one on top of the other is the first thing to look at. Get to know the Ctrl+Alt+l shortcut for code formatting. That should make issues like this pretty clear.

HTH, Mike

Comment: thank you :) Im new to android and java so I dont recognize mistages like that so easy. You saved me a lot of work